# CommandBinding refresh on parameter changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need the command I am executing on a datagrids context menu to know which column was clicked on.

XAML

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" ContextMenuOpening="DataGrid_ContextMenuOpening">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Add Column" Command="{Binding AddColumn}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove Column" Command="{Binding RemoveColumn}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void DataGrid_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    var current = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
    while(current != null && !(current is DataGridCell))
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    var cell = current as DataGridCell;
    foreach (var item in dataGrid.ContextMenu.Items.OfType<MenuItem>())
    {
        item.CommandParameter = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        (item.Command as DelegateCommand<object>)?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

I'm having to break MVVM by having the view tell the VM command that its execution has changed because the command binding doesn't seem to refresh on the parameter changing. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: there is no CommandParameter  binding as i'm not aware of a way to bind to bind a contextMenu to the sub element its called on, but the issue is that there is no link between the Commnd parameter and the Cimmand CanExecute call even though the parameter has a baring on it the command can execute or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having to break MVVM by having the view tell the VM command that its execution has changed because the command binding doesn't seem to refresh on the parameter changing.

The fundamental problem here seems to be that `MenuItem` tests whether (in effect) `Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter)` to update its own `Enabled` property when `Command` changes, but not when `CommandParameter` changes.

It seems to me that the least inelegant way of working around this (IMO) bug in WPF is to subclass `MenuItem` and use `DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata` to register a callback on `CommandParameterProperty` which updates an overridden `IsEnabledCore` property. To really do it properly you'd want to also override metadata for `CommandTargetProperty` and handle `RoutedCommand` specially, as in `CommandHelpers.CanExecuteCommandSource`.

An alternative approach, which would be hackier and require more XAML but wouldn't get quite so deep into the inner workings of WPF, would be an `IMultiValueConverter` which takes two parameters (the command and the parameter) and returns a parameterless command. Then you could set up multibindings such that a change in the parameter causes the `MenuItem`'s `Command` to change, triggering its `CanExecute` test.

Both of these approaches would require changes in the XAML of all the grids, but no per-grid codebehind. They would also eliminate the assumption, which IMO is one of the nastiest problems of the codebehind in the question, that all commands are instances of `DelegateCommand<object>`.

(The other nasty problem is that if the `while` loop is broken because `current == null`, the body of the second loop will throw a `NullReferenceException`).

Comment: taken a while but nice to finally have a well thought out relevant answer, the while loop would only have been a nasty problem if current could be null,in reality there was no way to open the context menu over a non cell element in the grid but for robustness i had added a null check on cell after i asked this question

Comment: i also agree whole heartedly about allowing the binding on none constant parameters that don't cause a binding refresh is definitely a bug, i'm hoping that now WPF has gone open source the community will start updating the 2005 wpf spec even the slightly improved 2008 spec was never incorporated into studio, hardly any wonder it never managed to displace win forms

Answer (score 4):

OK several years later and looking back I now know what I was doing wrong

this is a misuse of the command parameter

the command parameter is not a variable that you pass into the command on execution to relay the state of the application
its a constant used to specify behaviour.

if your command depends on a variable parameter you should create your own command that declares the variable as a property which can then trigger the correct events that are required to notify the view of the state change

```
public class ColumnCommand:ICommand,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ActiveColumn{get;set;}
    //etc;
}
```

then you could use the parameter to set if the command performs an add or a remove by passing in the string add or remove as the command parameter as this behaviour will not change during the lifespan of the command binding

this then allows the VM to update itself and work as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the search for the current column to:

```
private void DataGrid_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

  DataGridColumn currentColumn = dataGrid.CurrentColumn;
  if (currentColumn != null)
  {
     ...
```

Comment: i believe that currentColumn is the one that currently possesses the focus not the one under the mouse so would require the user to left click before right clicking to bring up the context menu, so they are not synonymous but if that behaviour is what you want then you are perfect correct

Comment: @MikeT. That's correct. But yo should carefully consider, if it's a good idea to manipulate columns that isn't the one focused/active.

Comment: i'm not disagreeing just saying this like many questions have multiple viewpoints that can make the correct answer wildly different, eg i change the value of column A then right click on Column E and select delete. which is the safest interpretation of the users intention deleting column A or E? i would say in most circumstances that E the source of the manipulation command is the better option than the source of the previous manipulation command, but it can definitely be argued both ways

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example using the `CommandParameter`. It's a little verbose, but `ContextMenu` bindings often are.

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove Column" Command="{Binding RemoveColumn}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Does that refresh the commands CanExecute when you move over a new column?

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].